# How to build open xml source code?

Tags: openxml-sdk

For one of my projects I want to embedd the open xml into one of my dlls.
I started downloading master Open xml from below address:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK
And tried to build it first, but to my dismay its saying
The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found

I have looked at below address and I saw I have installed these .net cores:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk

1.0.0, 1.1.9, 1.1.10, 2.0.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.201, 2.1.202, 2.1.400, 2.1.401

In the cs project its written netstandard1.3 is needed. But I can not find this package on microsoft website.

Do you know how I can build OpenXml?

Comment: Did you read and follow the [Build Instructions?](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#build-instructions)

Comment: Hi Robert, Yes Its just saying open it by visual studio and start building it normally, but openxml does not load completely at first which might be some .net core not installed but I dont know what.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting an error "The local source 'H:\Nuget' doesn't exist" when I try to do Nuget package restore.  Nuget says all dependencies are installed, Visual Studio says they aren't, and the project owner has apparently locked out the ability to re-install Nuget packages.  I see you've already filed a [bug report](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/522).

Comment: OK, the error was my fault, so I'm rebuilding.  It's taking awhile; the project wants to pull down a whole bunch of nuget packages.

Comment: This might be a problem with the nuget.org site.  I'm getting several timeouts downloading nuget packages, and attempting to download them manually is very sluggish.  But this isn't the best possible internet connection, and nuget.org can be fussy about that.

Comment: The problem is I dont want to have huge amount of dll in my output. As I want to embedd all of them in my assembly but I did not want to use nuget mode.

Comment: I don't think you have a choice if you want to build the project.